# I'm unable to cast numbers as float64 using bigquery, keep getting bad double value errors

Tags: sql, string, function, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract numbers as substrings from between certain characters before casting them as float64 using BigQuery, but I'm getting a Bad Double Value error for some values. I tried using safe_cast to identify which values cause the error and they return as null (as expected) but I can't seem to figure out why these values can't be casted as float64 since they are in fact numbers. The only thing in common with the anomalies is that the first number extracted in a row is 0 but there are other values which do this and are casted fine.

This is an example of the string which numbers are extracted from: `AOS-1545902(NCP)*0@84‬#475` which is `object_text` stored in a table named `tr`.
So in this case, the first number that is extracted is 0 from between the '*' and '@', the second is 84 from between '@' and '#', and the last one would be 475 after the '#'.

This is the query that I am using to extract the numbers and cast them to float64:

```
cast(substr(tr.object_text, strpos(tr.object_text,'*')+1, (strpos(tr.object_text,'@')-(strpos(tr.object_text,'*')+1))) as float64) AS FP_Share,
```

```
safe_cast(substr(tr.object_text, strpos(tr.object_text,'@')+1, (strpos(tr.object_text,'#')-(strpos(tr.object_text,'@')+1))) as float64) AS V_Share,
```

```
cast(substr(tr.object_text, strpos(tr.object_text,'#')+1) as float64) as Cust_Price,
```

From these, V_Share(the number between the '@' and '#') is the one that has these anomalies and when I extract the number without casting it to float64 using this query:

```
substr(tr.object_text, strpos(tr.object_text,'@')+1, (strpos(tr.object_text,'#')-(strpos(tr.object_text,'@')+1))) AS noCast_V_Share,
```

There are a total of 8 of these anomalies as you can see in the snippet below:
[Results Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lfymv.png)

Hoping someone could help me out with this!

Comment: There seem to be some invisible character(s) (possibly an invisible UTF8 character) in your string; `Bad double value: 84\342\200\254` is the error I get when testing your example.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards but these strings are entered into the database manually so I'm not sure how someone could enter an invisible utf-8 character just by typing. Thanks for the reply I'll look into it on a deeper level. Still open to any more suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to have unprintable characters causing problems in your extraction, you could use [REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to extract only the numbers (and possibly period if required) which should result in a valid conversion, something like;

```
CAST(
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(
    SUBSTR(tr.object_text, 
      STRPOS(tr.object_text,'@')+1, 
      (STRPOS(tr.object_text,'#')-(STRPOS(tr.object_text,'@')+1))), 
    '[0-9.]+'
  ) AS FLOAT64
) AS V_Share
```

Comment: This is exactly what the issue was, I identified the anomalies to be containing these characters "â€¬" which should absolutely not be a part of the entries, still unsure how they got there but REGEXP_EXTRACT should definitely resolve this! Thanks alot!